# fetching from an api - state react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an app that fetches current weather for a specified location.

I want to display current time but i have to use "slice()" method to get rid of the first part of the string that looks like this: "localtime: '2022-05-12 13:39' ".

The problem is with `useEffect()` and states in the context file.

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

    const Context = createContext({
      weather: {},
      place: {},
    });

    export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
      const [place, setPlace] = useState({});

      useEffect(() => {
        const getWeatherData = async () => {
          try {
            const request = await axios.get(
              "http://api.weatherstack.com/current"
            );

            const currentWeather = request.data.current;
            const currentPlace = request.data.location;

            setWeather(currentWeather);
            setPlace(currentPlace);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        };

        getWeatherData();
      }, []);

      console.log(weather);
      console.log(place);

      const context = {
        weather,
        place,
      };
      return <Context.Provider value={context}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
    };

    export default Context;
```

When i console.log my states (lines 33 & 34 in context file) i get this result:

**result**
[image: result]

So on the first render they're undefined but then useEffect runs and update them.

I assume that this is why my "splice()" method does not work properly.

```
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import IconWind from "../icons/icon-wind";
    import IconWindDirection from "../icons/icon-wind-direction";
    // import IconHumidity from "../icons/icon-humidity";
    import { useContext } from "react";
    import Context from "../../store/context";

    const WeatherDisplay = () => {
      const current = useContext(Context);

      const currentDay = new Date(current.place.localtime).toLocaleString("en-us", {
        weekday: "long",
      });

      const currentTime = current.place.localtime.slice(10);

      return (
        <Wrapper>
          <div>
            <PrimaryInfo>
              <h1>{current.place.name},</h1>
              <h2>{current.weather.temperature}°</h2>
              <p>
                {currentDay}, {currentTime}
              </p>
            </PrimaryInfo>
            <AdditionalInfo>
              <p>
                <IconWind /> Wind Speed: {current.weather.wind_speed}
              </p>
              <p>
                <IconWindDirection /> Wind Direction: {current.weather.wind_dir}
              </p>
              <p>Atmospheric pressure: {current.weather.pressure}</p>
              <p>Humidity: {current.weather.humidity}</p>
            </AdditionalInfo>
          </div>
        </Wrapper>
      );
    };

    const Wrapper = styled.section`
      width: 50%;
      border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;

      & > div {
        height: 100%;
        padding-left: 4rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    `;

    const PrimaryInfo = styled.section`
      margin-bottom: 10rem;
      h1 {
        font-size: 5rem;
      }

      h2 {
        font-size: 4rem;
        margin: 1rem 0rem;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 2.4rem;
      }
    `;

    const AdditionalInfo = styled.div`
      p {
        margin: 1rem 0rem;
        font-size: 1.2rem;

        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
    `;
    export default WeatherDisplay;
```

**splice logs**
[image: splice logs]

I tried to check if they already have content but still didnt work:

```
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import IconWind from "../icons/icon-wind";
    import IconWindDirection from "../icons/icon-wind-direction";
    // import IconHumidity from "../icons/icon-humidity";
    import { useContext } from "react";
    import Context from "../../store/context";

    const WeatherDisplay = () => {
      const current = useContext(Context);

      let currentDay;
      let currentTime;

      if (current.place.length > 0 && current.weather.length > 0) {
        currentDay = new Date(current.place.localtime).toLocaleString("en-us", {
          weekday: "long",
        });

        currentTime = current.place.localtime.slice(10);
      }

      console.log( currentDay);
      console.log( currentTime);

      return (
        <Wrapper>
          <div>
            <PrimaryInfo>
              <h1>{current.place.name},</h1>
              <h2>{current.weather.temperature}°</h2>
              <p>
                {currentDay}, {currentTime}
              </p>
            </PrimaryInfo>
            <AdditionalInfo>
              <p>
                <IconWind /> Wind Speed: {current.weather.wind_speed}
              </p>
              <p>
                <IconWindDirection /> Wind Direction: {current.weather.wind_dir}
              </p>
              <p>Atmospheric pressure: {current.weather.pressure}</p>
              <p>Humidity: {current.weather.humidity}</p>
            </AdditionalInfo>
          </div>
        </Wrapper>
      );
    };

    const Wrapper = styled.section`
      width: 50%;
      border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;

      & > div {
        height: 100%;
        padding-left: 4rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    `;

    const PrimaryInfo = styled.section`
      margin-bottom: 10rem;
      h1 {
        font-size: 5rem;
      }

      h2 {
        font-size: 4rem;
        margin: 1rem 0rem;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 2.4rem;
      }
    `;

    const AdditionalInfo = styled.div`
      p {
        margin: 1rem 0rem;
        font-size: 1.2rem;

        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
    `;
    export default WeatherDisplay;
```

It just displays currentDay and currentTime as undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you wrap WeatherDisplay with ContextProvider ?
Something like
<ContextProvider><WeatherDisplay/> </ContextProvider>

Comment: Whole app is wrapped with provider

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward... until `getWeatherData()` resolves, `place` is an empty object with no `localtime` property